# Problems erasing HTTP Cookie

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, cookies, webforms

I have a cookie which stores user info like username, companID etc.

I need to be able to update the cookie if the user logs off and back on using a different account.

The problem I have is that I can't get rid of the previous details. I am expiring the cookie and then trying to give it a new company ID which it will then use to collect the user details but it won't overwrite it.

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserInfo"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}

UserInfo.Values.Add("CompanyID", Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]));
Response.Cookies.Add(UserInfo);
```

Now after this the cookie still stored the old details with old company ID.

Comment: Try `Response.Cookies.Set(UserInfo);`

Comment: Just tried it, still exactly the same.

Comment: have u tried to assign path as well like `myCookie.Path="";`,use firebug to trace cookie path.

Comment: show the code adding the cookie also?

Comment: try this as well To clear the Cookies,

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CookieName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d)`;

Comment: HttpCookie UserInfo = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");

Comment: Just tried the HttpContext, that also didn't work.

Comment: then use firebug to trace cookie path and add like `myCookie.Path="";`

Comment: won't it just be "/" ?

Comment: if it works with just using `/` then good for u else try to find it's path by firebug.

Comment: When I opened firefox it loaded the correctly with the correct details (because of first time load) then in firebug there are no cookies listed.

Comment: OK got it now, the path is /

Comment: so try to add that path `myCookie.Path="/";`

Comment: I have just tried it and no change.

Comment: I can see that sometimes the cookie does overwrite it's old value and sometimes it doesn't the problem is trying to understand the difference and I just can't find it. I am also using separate cookies now for CompanyID and the other stuff.